# Wrapping text in widget - Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, word-wrap

I have code like that, and I would like to wrap text in 'comment' part.

```
   <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'id',
            'place_id',
            'place_rating',
            'comment:ntext',
            'hire_price',
            'additional_cost',
            'presentation_id',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

I found advice, that I should put `'style' => 'text-wrap'` somewhere, but have no idea where, I tried some places, but with no good effect.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: In the penultimate line: `$tableOptions = ['class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered text-wrap'],`

Answer (score 1):

Create a new css rule in your stylesheet and add a class `text-wrap` or do it directly as follows

**method 1:**

```
'contentOptions' => ['style' => ['max-width' => '100px;', 'height' => '100px']]
```

**Update**

```
[
    'label' => 'Comment',
    'attribute' => 'comment',
    'format'=>'ntext',
    'contentOptions' => ['style' => ['max-width' => '100px;', 'height' => '100px']]
],
```

or add class inside css and do following

**method 2:**

```
 'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'text-wrap']
```

***Add below css code in your css file***

```
.text-wrap{
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap; /* Newer versions of Chrome/Safari*/
word-break: break-all;
white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: But where EXACTLY put `'contentOptions' => ['style' => ['max-width' => '100px;', 'height' => '100px']]`?

Comment: as mentioned by `vishub` , you need to add it in attribute options

Comment: Okay, but I tried that and didn't notice any difference

Comment: refer the updated code and add the same in your gridview

Comment: Okay, I did as you told me, but it changed width of the cells, not the text wrapping - now it's going across all the following columns.

Comment: it looks like you have to make changes in your css. refer the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Add `contentOptions` in GridView

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'tableOptions' => ['class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered'],
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'place_id',
        'place_rating',
        [
           'attribute' => 'comment',
           'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'text-wrap'],
        ],
        'hire_price',
        'additional_cost',
        'presentation_id',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: It didn't change anything :(